# send FILE with AJAX and refresh table

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

Hi i try send a file with ajax and copy this file in my server, but i dont know how i refresh my table with the response of the ajax call. This is my code:

//This my function

```
function upload(){
var sampleFile = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("sampleFile",sampleFile);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","upload.htm", true);
xhr.send(formdata);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
         $('#table').html(data);//data always is empty i dont know how i get the list for refresh my table

    }   
};
```

}

//And this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Set<Object> upload(@RequestParam("sampleFile") CommonsMultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         {if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {

            //Copy file in server

    //Getting set<Object>



        }
        catch(Exception e){
        //thow exception

        }
      //return set<Object>
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` to inspect the response....

Comment: I inspect the response and i saw this: response = ""; responseText="";responseType="";responseXml= null; i think that my controller dont send nothing to response and  i need the set<object> in the function js to refresh the table. Maybe the controller is not write nothing?¿